# What is the exact NULL value for a field in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, null

Title says it all pretty much. What is the exact value that is assigned to a(n) a)Arithmetic b)String c)Logical field to represent NULL, in Oracle DBMS?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null is the absence of meaning, the absence of value. What gets assigned is `null`. Not even an ASCII `null` (ascii value `0`) but nothing.

That's why there's a special operation to test for `null` . This will return false:

```
...
where col1 = null
```

We need to test for:

```
where col1 is null
```

---

> "we were asked by a professor at uni to find what exactly that value is in these 3 respective cases"

Okay, let's investigate that. Here is a table with two rows:

```
SQL> create table t42 (
  2    type varchar2(10)
  3      , colv varchar2(10)
  4      , coln number
  5      , cold date
  6      )
  7 /

Table created.

SQL> insert into t42 values ('not null', 'X', 1, sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t42 values ('all null', null, null, null);

1 row created.

SQL>Exp
```

Oracle has a function `dump()` which shows us the datatype and content of the passed value. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions055.htm#SQLRF00635).

What does `dump()` tell us about our two rows?

```
SQL> select type
  2         , dump(colv) as colv
  3         , dump(coln) as coln
  4         , dump(cold) as cold
  5  from t42;

TYPE       COLV                 COLN                 COLD
---------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------------------------------
not null   Typ=1 Len=1: 88      Typ=2 Len=2: 193,2   Typ=12 Len=7: 120,117,4,29,6,60,44
all null   NULL                 NULL                 NULL

SQL>
```

So: the `null` columns have no data type, no value.

---

> "I don't think dump is suitable for supporting any argument over what "exactly" gets stored to represent a null - because if the expression is null, it simply returns null by definition "

@JeffreyKemp makes a fair point. So let's dip a toe into the internals. The first step is to dump the data block(s);l the dump is written to a trace file:

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
USER is "SYS"
SQL> select dbms_rowid.rowid_relative_fno(t42.rowid) as fno
  2         , dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(t42.rowid) as blk
  3  from a.t42
  4  /

     FNO      BLK
-------- --------
      11      132
      11      132

SQL> alter system dump datafile 11 block 132;

System altered.

SQL> select value from v$diag_info where name = 'Default Trace File';

VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/oracle/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orcl/orcl/trace/orcl_ora_3275.trc

SQL>
```

Because T42 is small it fits into only one block. Here is the interesting bit of the dump:

```
data_block_dump,data header at 0x805664
===============
tsiz: 0x1f98
hsiz: 0x16
pbl: 0x00805664
     76543210
flag=--------
ntab=1
nrow=2
frre=-1
fsbo=0x16
fseo=0x1f73
avsp=0x1f5d
tosp=0x1f5d
0xe:pti[0]  nrow=2  offs=0
0x12:pri[0] offs=0x1f7f
0x14:pri[1] offs=0x1f73
block_row_dump:
tab 0, row 0, @0x1f7f
tl: 25 fb: --H-FL-- lb: 0x1  cc: 4
col  0: [ 8]  6e 6f 74 20 6e 75 6c 6c
col  1: [ 1]  58
col  2: [ 2]  c1 02
col  3: [ 7]  78 75 05 01 02 08 08
tab 0, row 1, @0x1f73
tl: 12 fb: --H-FL-- lb: 0x1  cc: 1
col  0: [ 8]  61 6c 6c 20 6e 75 6c 6c
end_of_block_dump
End dump data blocks tsn: 33 file#: 11 minblk 132 maxblk 132
```

We can see there are two rows in the table. The first row has entries for four columns; this is the `'not null'` row. The second row has only one column: this is the `'all null'` row. So, Jeffrey is quite right. All the trailing fields are null so Oracle stores nothing for them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What you're saying is what i've found so far, that NULL is essentially the abscence of a value and cannot really be matched to a value. However, a few weeks ago we were asked by a professor at uni to find what exactly that value is in these 3 respective cases i've mentioned above. That's the reason i wanted to look more into it, cause i don't think he is bluffing and that there's possibly an answer i can't really find.

Comment: If answering questions on SO has taught me anything I'm afraid it is that  professors are frequently bluffing when they set tasks for their students :)

Comment: I don't think `dump` is suitable for supporting any argument over what "exactly" gets stored to represent a `null` - because if the expression is null, it simply returns `null` by definition (http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions063.htm#SQLRF00635). Internally, my understanding is that in a normal Oracle data block, `null` is stored as either (a) a single zero for column length, if there are any trailing non-null fields later in the same record; or (b) nothing, if there are no trailing non-null fields in the record.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from APC is fully right, let's give some information on "what does it mean":

1. Arithmetic: `NULL` basically means "not defined". Every math operation with `NULL` (i.e. "not defined") also returns `NULL`
2. String: `NULL` is an empty string, i.e. `'' IS NULL` returns `TRUE` - this behavior of Oracle is different to many others RDBMS.
3. Logical: I assume you mean what happens to `BOOLEAN` data types. Unlike almost any other programming language in PL/SQL a `BOOLEAN` variable can have **three** different states: `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `NULL`. Be aware of this special behavior when you work with BOOLEAN in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @APC, in DB there is a something like 'ternary logic' in comparison operations, when we can say that value are equal, not equal and the third is "we don't know", cause of it value absence NULL, and even comparison of to NULL values gives  the NULL, meaning that we have no information about operands